# Singular ideals and rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

In Lam's book, Corollary (7.4)(2) says that for a nonzero ring $R$ we have $Z(R_R)≠ R$, where $Z(R_R) $ stands for the singular ideal of $R$.. But, some nonzero commutative rings are "singular" in the sense that $Z(R_R)=R$, for example, any commutative nil ring is singular: [this article Prop. 2.1](http://www.austms.org.au/Publ/Jamsa/V64P2/abs/k09/) Are these (the corollary and the proposition) not inconsistent with each other?

Thanks for any reply!

Comment: It sounds like Lam is working with unital rings and the second source isn't (considering most nil rings are nonunital).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lam works almost exclusively with rings with identity on those books.

The identity obviously cannot be in either singular ideal (since its annihilator $\{0\}$ is never essential.)